# Sliding puzzle related path finding

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let a sliding puzzle of size $m\times n$, with $p$ empty positions be given. Further, let $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ be two arbitrary positions inside the puzzle. What conditions have to be fulfilled s.t. it is possible to clear a path between $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$, if each block of the puzzle is restricted to move not further than one position (distance one)?

This question concerns me for a while now. I listed my findings below, but I am struggling to prove them. I don't know how to find publications on such a topic if they even exists? Consequently my questions are:

- Is the formulation of the problem comprehensible? If not, please ask!
- Is there some literature on such a topic, or something similar?
- How could a proof look like?

---

I found that the following inequality is a necessary condition for the solution of the problem:

$p \geq |x - x'| + |y-y'| + 1$

It states that the number of empty positions has to be at least as big as the number of positions on the shortest path from $(x,y)$ to $(x',y')$.

For my needs it would suffice to show, that there exists a path between all source/target-pairs, if the number of blocked positions ($mn - p$) is bounded by the minimum of m and n minus one.

$mn - p \leq \min (m,n) - 1$